# How to solve "total size of new array must be unchanged error" in Python?

Tags: arrays, keras, reshape, autoencoder

I am implementing the following model:

```
def ConnectomeCNNAutoencoder(input_shape, keep_pr=0.65, n_filter=32, n_dense1=64, n_classes=2, 
                      mode="autoencoder", sign="neg"):

input_1 = Input(shape=input_shape)
# Convolutional Encoder 
bias_init = tf.constant_initializer(value=0.001)
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=n_filter , kernel_size=(1,input_shape[1]), strides=(1, 1),
                                 padding= "valid", activation="selu", # "selu"
                                 kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                                 bias_initializer=bias_init, name="conv1")(input_1)
dropout1 = Dropout(keep_pr, name="dropout1")(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(filters=n_filter*2 , kernel_size=(input_shape[1],1), strides=(1, 1),
                                 padding= "valid", activation="selu", 
                                 kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                                 bias_initializer=bias_init, name="conv2")(dropout1)
encoded = Dropout(keep_pr, name="dropout2")(conv2)

# Classification
reshape = Reshape((n_filter*2,), name="reshape1")(encoded)
dense1 = Dense(n_dense1, activation="selu", name="dense1", kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1_l2())(reshape) 

if n_classes == 1:
    activation = "sigmoid"
else:
    activation = "softmax"
output = Dense(n_classes, activation=activation, name="output")(dense1)

# Decoder
dense2 = Dense(n_dense1, activation="selu", name="dense2")(output) 
dim_reconstruct = tuple(encoded.get_shape().as_list())
reshape2 = Reshape(dim_reconstruct[1:], name="reshape2")(dense2)

conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=n_filter*2 , kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1, 1),
                                  padding= "valid", activation="selu", # "selu"
                                  kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                                  bias_initializer=bias_init, name="conv3")(reshape2)
conv4 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=n_filter , kernel_size=(input_shape[1],1), strides=(1, 1),
                                  padding= "valid", activation="selu", # "selu"
                                  kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                                  bias_initializer=bias_init, name="conv4")(conv3)

if sign == "pos":
    reconstructed_activation = "sigmoid"
elif sign == "neg":
    reconstructed_activation = "tanh"
    
reconstructed_input = Conv2DTranspose(filters=input_shape[-1], kernel_size=(1,input_shape[1]), strides=(1, 1),
                                  padding= "valid", activation=reconstructed_activation, 
                                  kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
                                  bias_initializer=bias_init, name='autoencoder')(conv4)

if mode == "autoencoder":
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=[output, reconstructed_input])
elif mode =="encoder":
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=encoded)
elif mode == "decoder":
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=reconstructed_input)
return model
```

The model works fine when `n_filter=32` and `n_dense1=64`, but when I change these variable for other values, this error pops up: `"ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged"`.
I know that is related tothe use of Reshape in `reshape2`, but I don't know how to solve this.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears in this line:

```py
reshape2 = Reshape(dim_reconstruct[1:], name="reshape2")(dense2)
```

Tensor `dense2` should be of the shape that could be 'transformed' into shape of `dim_reconstruct[1:]`. It means that the product of values of `dim_reconstruct[1:]` should be equal to the shape of `dense2` (excluding zeroth dimension - batch size, because `keras` doesn't count it when derives dimensionalities of tensors).

If `n_filters = 30`, `dim_reconstruct[1:]` will be `[1, 1, 60]` - because you multiplied `n_filters` by 2. But number of dense filters has to be equal to the product of values from `[1, 1, 60]`, i.e., 60.

I couldn't find any image with transformation of 1d into 3d array. But there's and example with 2d arrays: one can't fit array `[1,2,3,4,5]` into 2x3 2d array, but can transform `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` into something like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

So, you could set `n_units1` to 60 when call `ConnectomeCNNAutoencoder`, or you could derive it automatically instead:

```py
    # Decoder
    dim_reconstruct = tuple(encoded.get_shape().as_list())  # say, (1, 1, 60)
    n_dense2 = np.product(dim_reconstruct[1:])  # will be 60
    dense2 = Dense(n_dense2, activation="selu", name="dense2")(output)
    reshape2 = Reshape(dim_reconstruct[1:], name="reshape2")(dense2)
```

Complete example (I removed some arguments that were equal to default values):

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dropout, Reshape, Dense, Conv2DTranspose


def ConnectomeCNNAutoencoder(input_shape,
                             keep_pr=0.65,
                             n_filter=32,
                             n_dense1=64,
                             n_classes=2,
                             mode="autoencoder",
                             sign="neg"):
    input_1 = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Convolutional Encoder
    bias_init = tf.constant_initializer(value=0.001)
    conv1 = Conv2D(filters=n_filter,
                   kernel_size=(1, input_shape[1]),
                   strides=(1, 1),
                   activation="selu",  # "selu"
                   bias_initializer=bias_init,
                   name="conv1")(input_1)
    dropout1 = Dropout(keep_pr, name="dropout1")(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(filters=n_filter * 2,
                   kernel_size=(input_shape[1], 1),
                   strides=(1, 1),
                   activation="selu",
                   bias_initializer=bias_init,
                   name="conv2")(dropout1)
    encoded = Dropout(keep_pr, name="dropout2")(conv2)

    # Classification
    reshape = Reshape((n_filter * 2,), name="reshape1")(encoded)
    dense1 = Dense(n_dense1,
                   activation="selu",
                   name="dense1",
                   kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1_l2())(reshape)

    if n_classes == 1:
        activation = "sigmoid"
    else:
        activation = "softmax"

    output = Dense(n_classes, activation=activation, name="output")(dense1)

    # Decoder - Changes here
    dim_reconstruct = tuple(encoded.get_shape().as_list())
    n_dense2 = np.product(dim_reconstruct[1:])
    dense2 = Dense(n_dense2, activation="selu", name="dense2")(output)
    reshape2 = Reshape(dim_reconstruct[1:], name="reshape2")(dense2)

    conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=n_filter * 2,
                            kernel_size=(1, 1),
                            strides=(1, 1),
                            activation="selu",  # "selu"
                            bias_initializer=bias_init,
                            name="conv3")(reshape2)
    conv4 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=n_filter,
                            kernel_size=(input_shape[1], 1),
                            strides=(1, 1),
                            activation="selu",  # "selu"
                            bias_initializer=bias_init,
                            name="conv4")(conv3)

    if sign == "pos":
        reconstructed_activation = "sigmoid"
    elif sign == "neg":
        reconstructed_activation = "tanh"

    reconstructed_input = Conv2DTranspose(filters=input_shape[-1],
                                          kernel_size=(1, input_shape[1]),
                                          strides=(1, 1),
                                          activation=reconstructed_activation,
                                          bias_initializer=bias_init,
                                          name='autoencoder')(conv4)

    if mode == "autoencoder":
        model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=[output, reconstructed_input])
    elif mode == "encoder":
        model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=encoded)
    elif mode == "decoder":
        model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_1, outputs=reconstructed_input)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected mode: %s" % mode)
    return model


model = ConnectomeCNNAutoencoder((32, 32, 3), n_filter=30, n_dense1=65)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation @MikhailStepanov!! Just saved my day!